# Replace Conditional with Polymorphism in a proper way?

Tags: architecture, refactoring, software, architectural-patterns, polymorphism

Consider two classes `Dog` and `Cat` both conforming to `Animal` protocol (in terms of Swift programming language. That'd be interface in Java/C#).

We have a screen displaying a mixed list of dogs and cats. There's `Interactor` class that handles logic behind scenes.

Now we want to present a confirmation alert to the user when he wants to delete a cat. However, dogs need to be deleted immediately without any alerts. The method with conditionals would look like this:

```
func tryToDeleteModel(model: Animal) {
    if let model = model as? Cat {
        tellSceneToShowConfirmationAlert()
    } else if let model = model as? Dog {
        deleteModel(model: model)
    }
}
```

How can this code be refactored? It obviously smells

Answer (score 9):

You're letting the protocol type *itself* determine behavior.  You want to treat all protocols the same throughout your program *except* in the implementing class itself.  Doing it this way is respecting Liskov's Substitution Principle, which says you should be able to pass either `Cat` or `Dog` (or any other protocols you might eventually have under `Animal` potentially), and have it work indifferently.

So presumably you'd add an `isCritical` func to `Animal` to be implemented by both `Dog` and `Cat`. Anything implementing `Dog` would return false and anything implementing `Cat` would return true.

At that point, you'd only need to do (My apologies if syntax isn't correct.  Not a user of Swift):

```
func tryToDeleteModel(model: Animal) {
    if model.isCritical() {
        tellSceneToShowConfirmationAlert()
    } else {
        deleteModel(model: model)
    }
}
```

There is only a small problem with that, and that is that `Dog` and `Cat` are protocols, meaning they in themselves don't determine what `isCritical` returns, leaving this to every implementing class to decide for themselves.  If you have a lot of implementations, it would probably be worth your while to create an extendable class of `Cat` or `Dog` which already correctly implements `isCritical` and effectively clearing all implementating classes from the need to override `isCritical`.

If this doesn't answer your question, please write in the comments and I'll expand my answer accordingly!

Comment: It's a little unclear in the statement of the question, but `Dog` and `Cat` are described as classes, while `Animal` is a protocol that's implemented by each of those classes. So there's a bit of a mismatch between the question and your answer.

Comment: So you suggest to let model decide whether to present a confirmation popup or not? But what if there's a heavy logic involved, like show popup only if there are 10 cats displayed? The logic depends on `Interactor` state now

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the unclear question, I've made few edits. Should be more clear now

Comment: This kind of behaviour should not be linked to the model. It depends on the context and not the entity itself. I think Cat and Dog are more likely to be POJO. Behaviours should be handle at other places and be able to change according to the context. Delegating behaviours or methods which behaviours will rely on in Cat or Dog will lead to too much responsibilities in such classes.

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer Please note that it isn't determining behavior.  It is merely stating whether or not it is a critical class.  Behaviors throughout the program which need to know if it is a critical class can then evaluate and act accordingly.  If this is indeed a property which differentiates how instances in both `Cat` and `Dog` are handled, it can and should be a common property in `Animal`.  Doing anything else is asking for a maintenance headache later.

Answer (score 4):

### Tell vs. Ask

The conditional approach you're showing we would call "***ask***".  This is where the consuming client *asks* "what kind are you?" and customizes their behavior and interaction with objects accordingly.

This contrasts with the alternative we call "***tell***".  Using *tell*, you push more of the work into the polymorphic implementations, so that the consuming client code is simpler, without conditionals, and common regardless of the possible implementations.

Since you want to use a confirming alert, you could make that an explicit capability of the interface.  So, you might have a boolean method that optionally checks with the user and returns the confirmation boolean.  In the classes that don't want to confirm, they simply override with `return true;`.  Other implementations might dynamically determine if they want to use confirmation.

The consuming client would always use the confirmation method regardless of the particular subclass it is working with, which makes the interaction *tell* instead of *ask*.

(Another approach would be to push the confirmation into the deletion, but that would surprise consuming clients who expect a deletion operation to succeed.)

Comment: So you suggest to let model decide whether to present a confirmation popup or not? But what if there's a heavy logic involved, like show popup only if there are 10 cats displayed? The logic depends on `Interactor` state now

Comment: Ok, yes, that is a different question, requiring a different answer.

Answer (score 2):

Determining whether a confirmation is needed is the responsibility of the `Cat` class, so enable it to perform that action. I do not know Kotlin, so I'll express things in C#. Hopefully the ideas are then transferable to Kotlin too.

```
interface Animal
{
    bool IsOkToDelete();
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _confirmation;

    public Cat (Func<bool> confirmation) => _confirmation = confirmation;

    public bool IsOkToDelete() => _confirmation();
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public bool IsOkToDelete() => true;
}
```

Then, when creating a `Cat` instance, you supply it with `TellSceneToShowConfirmationAlert`, which will need to return `true` if OK to delete:

```
var model = new Cat(TellSceneToShowConfirmationAlert);
```

And then your function becomes:

```
void TryToDeleteModel(Animal model) 
{
    if (model.IsOKToDelete())
    {
        DeleteModel(model)
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this move the delete logic into the model? Wouldn't it be much better to use another object to handle this? Possibly a data structure like a Dictionary<Cat> inside an ApplicationService; check to see if the Cat exists and if it does then to fire off the confirmation alert?

Comment: @keelerjr12, it moves the responsibility for determining if a confirmation is needed for the delete into the `Cat` class. I'd argue that that is where it belongs. It doesn't get to decide how that confirmation is achieved (that is injected) and it doesn't delete itself. So no, it doesn't move the delete logic into the model.

Comment: I feel like this approach would lead to tons and tons of UI-related code attached to the class itself. If the class is intended to be used across multiple UI layers, the problem grows. However if this is a ViewModel type class, rather than a business entity, then it seems appropriate.

Comment: @Graham, yes that's definitely a risk with this approach: it relies on it being easy to inject `TellSceneToShowConfirmationAlert` into an instance of `Cat`. In situations where that's not an easy thing (such as in a multi-layered system where this functionality lies at a deep level), then this approach would not be a good one.

Comment: Exacty what I was getting at. A business entity vs a ViewModel class. In the business domain, a Cat shouldn’t know about UI related code. My family cat doesn’t alert anyone. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to go for a Visitor pattern.
I did a small implementation in Java. I'm not familiar with Swift, but you can adapt it easily.

The visitor

```
public interface AnimalVisitor<R>{
    R visitCat();
    R visitDog();
}
```

Your model

```
abstract class Animal { // can also be an interface like VisitableAnimal
    abstract <R> R accept(AnimalVisitor<R> visitor);
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public <R> R accept(AnimalVisitor<R> visitor) {
         return visitor.visitCat();
     }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    public <R> R accept(AnimalVisitor<R> visitor) {
         return visitor.visitDog();
     }
}
```

Calling the visitor

```
public void tryToDelete(Animal animal) {
    animal.accept( new AnimalVisitor<Void>() {
        public Void visitCat() {
            tellSceneToShowConfirmation();
            return null;
        }

        public Void visitDog() {
            deleteModel(animal);
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

You can have as much implementations of AnimalVisitor as you want.

Example:

```
public void isColorValid(Color color) {
    animal.accept( new AnimalVisitor<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean visitCat() {
            return Color.BLUE.equals(color);
        }

        public Boolean visitDog() {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```